# Boolean modifier isn't showing the entire shape of the cut in solid view mode or when I render it. Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

[image: So this is the shape I want to cut into another "wall" shape. You'll notice the back ridge of the cylinder shape. That is the part that isn't cutting properly.]So this is the shape I want to cut into another "wall" shape. You'll notice the back ridge of the cylinder shape. That is the part that isn't cutting properly

[image: This is where I have positioned the shape inside the "wall" shape.]This is where I have positioned the shape inside the "wall" shape

[image: The settings I used and applied for the Boolean modifier.]
The settings I used and applied for the Boolean modifier

[image: Now this is the result of the Boolean in the solid view. That back ridge doesn't show up at all.]Now this is the result of the Boolean in the solid view. That back ridge doesn't show up at all.

[image: When I use orthographic view I can see it.]When I use orthographic view I can see it.

[image: But if I use xray mode I can see it.]But if I use xray mode I can see it.

[image: Again it shows up in the wireframe view when I look into the "wall" shape.]Again it shows up in the wireframe view when I look into the "wall" shape
[image: But not when I look at it on wireframe view from the outside.]But not when I look at it on wireframe view from the outside.

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it, then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Without boolean - https://blend-exchange.com/b/OLw4aPNs  
with boolean - https://blend-exchange.com/b/ndOG5ykr

Answer (score 3):

Because you use just two joined cylinders as the boolean object (can be seen in your sixth screenshot). This is not a valid manifold. You either apply the cylinders separately with two *Boolean* modifiers or you model one valid manifold and use that.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Is there a reason why two joined meshes aren't valid?

Comment: A manifold is valid if it forms a single volume. This can't be the case when you only join two meshes. Even if they would perfectly fit at their (open) borders, you would at least have to merge the overlapping vertices afterwards.